# How to filter results of AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have an AutoCompleteTextView set to use a cursor which goes over my Contacts.  The problem is, I have it populating the dropdown correctly, but its not filtering the results after I type.

Here is my code for the cursor and setting of the adapter:

```
edt_Contact = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.compose_edtContact);

cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
        new String[] {Phone._ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER}, 
        null,null,null);
startManagingCursor(cursor);
String[] from = new String[] { Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER};
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.contact_name, R.id.contact_phoneNo};
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.simple_contact_textview, cursor, from, to);

edt_Contact.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And here is the xml for simple_contact_textview:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:padding="5sp" android:paddingBottom="5sp" android:background="#FFFFFFFF">
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/contact_name" 
        android:textColor="#FF000000" 
        android:textSize="20sp" 
        android:text="Name">
    </TextView>
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/contact_phoneNo" 
        android:paddingLeft="10sp" 
        android:textColor="#FF000000" 
        android:textSize="20sp" 
        android:text="Number" 
        android:ellipsize="end">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

How do I filter the dropdown results based on what the user is typing?  For instance, if the user starts typing "and", how would I have "andrew", "andy", and "mandy" appear?

Comment: I am doing something similiar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854336/autocompletetextview-backed-by-cursorloader

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Construct a `FilterQueryProvider` and pass it into `adapter.setFilterQueryProvider()`.

```
adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
    public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
        String s = '%' + constraint.toString() + '%';
        return getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
            new String[] {Phone._ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER},
            Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + ' LIKE ? OR ' + Phone.NUMBER + ' LIKE ?',
            new String[] { s, s },
            null);
    }
});
```

The code above will return results that match anywhere in the string (not just in the beginning. Also, since it uses parameterized queries, your users won't be able to damage the DB via a SQL injection attack.

(Not near an actual computer, so I can't test the above -- probably some syntax errors in there.)

Comment: Yup, this is what I ended up doing.  Thanks bud!

Comment: Any idea why `constraint.toString()` would cause a NPE to be thrown and caught in `CursorFilter.performFiltering` even though constraint is not null within `runQuery`?

Answer (score 1):

Finally tried something that worked:

```
private void initViews() {

    edt_Contact = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.compose_edtContact);

    cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
            new String[] {Phone._ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER}, 
            null,null,null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    String[] from = new String[] { Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER};
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.contact_name, R.id.contact_phoneNo};
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.simple_contact_textview, cursor, from, to);

    adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
            return getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                    new String[] {Phone._ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER}, 
                    Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE '" + constraint + "%'", 
                    null, null);
        }
    });

    edt_Contact.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Sorry if I robbed anyone of an answer.  All questions like this seem to have very low views and answers...

Comment: No problem. SO told me there was another answer right before I submitted mine, but it looks like you answered it quite a few minutes before I was ready to submit. Not sure why it took so long to notify me that another answer was available.