# Android - Do i really need FilterQueryProvider?

Tags: android

I working on a browser history application,
And using **CursorAdaptor** and **getContentResolver().query** to fetch the bookmark and history into **AutoCompleteTextView**,
Also apply the selection, sortorder and work well.

But i see in a post:
[How to filter results of AutoCompleteTextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300508/how-to-filter-results-of-autocompletetextview)

Someone said it must use **setFilterQueryProvider**, do any reason to do that?

Copy the code from that post :

```
cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
            new String[] {Phone._ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER}, 
            null,null,null);



  adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
            return getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                    new String[] {Phone._ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER}, 
                    Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE '" + constraint + "%'", 
                    null, null);
        }
    });
```

Why not just put the WHERE clause to  getContentResolver()?
Thanks you for help!
I am new to android development.